# couchbase nodes RAM is getting full frequently

Tags: couchbase

we have a 4 node cluster, with 24 GB RAM, out of which 18GB has been given to couchbase with zero replicaion.
We have a approx 10M of records in this cluster with ~2.5M/hour and expire old items.
My RAM Usage which is ~72GB is getting full every ~12 days, and i need to restart the cluster to fix this. After restart again the RAM usage is back to ~20GB.

Can someone please help to understand the reason for it.

FYI : Auto Compaction is set to 40% fragment level and Meta Data Purge Interval is set to 1 Day, -- which we reduced to do 2 hours. But it didn't help.

Comment: Couchbase caches as much as possible data in memory, so it's expected behavour to fill up almost all RAM. What is the actual error you get?

Comment: Couchbase version is 3.0.1..

Comment: @julian --  yes.., that's true.. Couchbase caches as much as possible data in memory. But the data size is ~22 GB, while the RAM Size 70GB. So the couchbase should not use memory more than(22GB+MetaData Size for 22GB) ... But the problem is it occupy all 70GB.   We are not getting any error regarding this until it started evicetion. The major problem is, when it gets full it started to evict items from memory and our Resident Ratio becomes zero in approx 15mins. while it was 100% just 15 mins before when couchbase started to evict items.

Answer (score 1):

Under scenarios with very high memory allocation churn Couchbase can experience memory fragmentation, which would cause the effects you are describing. This was addressed in the 4.x release by switching to jemalloc on non-Windows OSes and using tcmalloc with agressive decommit on Windows. I would suggest you download the RC version of Couchbase 4 (http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads#Couchbase_Server) and give it a try to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Didn't understand what do you mean by "high memory allocation". Is it mean very frequent new/update of CB documents or expire old items because of ttl. 
We have 2 more clusters of couchbase, with the same version 3.0.1, and are running smoothly fine.

Comment: High memory churn, meaning when Couchbase allocates and release a lot of memory frequently, like in your scenario with ttl and high rate of new writes.